# Solution of $5^{\log x}+5x^{\log 5}=3$

Tags: logarithms

Solve for $x$

$$5^{\log x}+5x^{\log 5}=3$$

where base of log is $a$, $a>0$ and $a \neq1$

Could someone hint as how to initiate this question? I am not having any idea as how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: $5^{\log x}=a^{\log 5 \log x}$.

Comment: $5^{\log x}=a^{\log 5\log x}=x^{\log 5}$, so your equation is $x^{\log 5}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing to remember is $\log b^c = c \log b.$ In your cases, $\log 5^{\log x} = \log x \; \log 5$ and $\log x^{\log 5} =  \log 5 \; \log x.$ Put them together,
$$ 5^{\log x} = x^{\log 5} $$

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the statement:
$$5^{\ln{x}} + 5\cdot5^{\log_{5}{x}\ln{5}} = 5^{\ln{x}} + 5\cdot5^{lnx} = 6\cdot5^{\ln{x}} = 3$$,then $$x = e^{\log_{5}{\frac{1}{2}}}$$